# What causes Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin " " from accessing a cross-origin frame?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I loaded a [website](https://gkwhelps.herokuapp.com) of my own design in an iframe. This website contains links to other cross-domain pages. I wrote a javascript function to retrieve the title of the current page contained in the iframe, but when I run my application at localhost:3000, I get the error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:3000" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

Even when I am using this javascript method on the page that was originally loaded in the iframe, I still get the same error.
I would like to know exactly what is causing this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) is a security feature that protects user data across origins.

Consider what would happen if you loaded my webmail service into a frame on your site and were then able to access the DOM of that page. This would be a security disaster.

Even just reading the title could expose if I was logged in (and thus had an account on the site) or not (and probably don’t) which would be useful information for constructing a phishing attack.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and is there an extension or a way to disable this policy?

Comment: Is this policy related to cors?

Comment: There are some circumstances where CORS can be used to relax the same origin policy. This isn’t one of them.

Comment: So if I understand correctly cors has nothing to do with this error, does it?

Comment: Correct. This is not a circumstance where CORS can help.

Comment: I just want to get the iframe contents height, so I don't have double scroll bars. Surely this is allowed?  (the content changed in the iframe dynamically, I own both domains, but they're no same origin). Calling `iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight` causes the origin issue